# Export iPhone App for WWDC Submission

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, export

I will shortly be applying for the WWDC Student Scholarship.  I have been working on an app that I would like to link to in my application.  The app is not currently on the App Store.

When I export the app by exporting the .ipa file through Xcode, and email it to a friend for testing, he is unable to transfer the app from iTunes to his iOS device.

I can set up an Ad Hoc profile for him so that he can test it, but I obviously don't have information affiliated with iPhones Apple will use to review the app once I submit it to them.

What must I do to allow the app to run on any iOS device without setting up Ad-Hoc accounts for each?

Comment: you're applying to? Same.... pretty psyched!

Comment: Same! Do you have any solutions...? It's a really brilliant app, and I'll do whatever it takes to get it to them.

Comment: Well they'll only accept it if its on the app store. BUt you won't have time to upload it... the review process is up to 10 days...
Whats the app?

Comment: The details on the submission don't mention that the app must be on the store. The ones I created were school projects, and thus I will be submitting them under that category on the form.

Comment: Do you have any apps on the store?

Comment: Yep.... Unfortunately got 3 crappy ones

Comment: And what sucks even more is I have amazing technology like augmented reality and facial recognition and rss feed apps I haven't uploaded... Because there is no real idea behind it but just a practice

Comment: Did you get accepted????
I didn't...

Comment: @RohanKapur to apply for the scholarship you have to be a student - you can be older than 17. I am 13 and got in, did you get in @TheKraken?

Comment: @LennyK Oh hey its you! On the Facebook page. I didn't realize you could be older than 17

Comment: No limit - David (from the FB group) was 22.

Comment: @LennyK, what specifically did you put on your application to get in? All modesty aside, I had a stellar application and was not accepted. I'd be very curious to know what you did. :)

Comment: @TheKraken, I actually have a copy of my application, but it's too large to fit into the comment.

Comment: Dropbox would be a great way to send it, or I'd be happy to give you my email. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the submission page? Login required: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/application/

It says your app must be on the App Store. First submit it to the App Store, then once it is approved you can apply for the student scholarship.

Comment: The app is the "relevant school project" also listed below.

Comment: Very well. You should link to your source code, that would be much easier for the both of you. They can compile it and sign it onto their devices much easier than you signing it for their devices.

Comment: Do you know of any potential code-signing or other compatibility issues that could arise out of doing this?

Comment: Yes, if your code is wrong and won’t run on their machines for some reason. As for code signing no, they’ll just sign it anew with their own profiles.

Comment: My code compiles and runs perfectly on my own devices. Is it safe to assume then that there should be no issues with running it on theirs?

Answer (score 1):

Without the device ID of the test phone, you can't distribute your app in development mode. One thing you could do is setup a free TestFlight account, include TestFlight in your app (takes about 10 mins to setup), and then include the TestFlight tester signup link with your application. Then if they want to try your app they can follow that link to register their device with TestFlight, then you'll get alerted when they do that and you can recompile your app with their device id and push it to them via TestFlight.